# data.frame - object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this function:

```
coeff_var <- function(data_stand) {

  percvar <- (sd(data_stand)/mean(data_stand)*100)
  return(percvar)
}


and I want to calculate multiple columns at a time. I have tried:
lapply(data_stand, coeff_var(data_stand))  
apply(data_stand,2, coeff_var(data_stand))
summarise(data, data_coeff_var = coeff_var(data_stand))
```

I also tried to unlist the object first:

```
as.numeric(unlist(data_stand))
```

and I get the following error:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
>     (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

data_stand looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have all numeric columns except for the first column, you can `lapply` like

```
data_stand[-1] <- lapply(data_stand[-1], coeff_var)
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data_stand %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, coeff_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
lapply(data_stand[,sapply(data_stand, is.numeric)], coeff_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_stand)[, lapply(.SD, function(x)
            if(is.numeric(x)) coeff_var(x) else NULL)]
```